# .. in file path, python os.chdir

Tags: python, cmd, operating-system, chdir

I have encountered something, I am building a command line tool in python.
Now I use the `os.chdir` to change the current working directory (with command `cd`).
I noticed that when I put `..` in the input, it brings me back in the directory tree.
For example, I am in directory `D:\pythonProject`
I input `cd ..`
So the chdir parameter is `D:\pythonProject\..` (I am using os.path.join). And then, the current working directory becomes `D:`. Obviously I can't go back more than that. But why does this happen? I didn't include handling for `..` in my code. Is it something that is built-in?

This is my function:

```
def change_working_dir(path):
    path_dest = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path)
    if os.path.exists(path_dest):
        if os.path.isdir(path_dest):
            os.chdir(path_dest)
        elif os.path.isfile(path_dest):
            os.startfile(path_dest)
        else:
            print("No such path.")
```

Thanks!

Comment: yes '..' is the built-in for the parent directory. if you try in your terminal, cd .. does the same

Comment: even if its in the end of a path yeah? so for example, ".." and "C:\python\.." would do the same of going back to "C:\"?

Comment: Just as a small correction/clarification, nat34. There is no directory ```D:```; that is only a drive with an identifying letter allocated. The root directory of a drive is ```\```, so the directory would be ```D:\```, _(i.e. the root directory of drive ```D:```)_.